# How to set column value based on another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "my_table", with 2 columns: "col_1" and "col_2".

`UPDATE my_table SET col_2 = 1 WHERE col_1 IN (12,13,14,15);`

`UPDATE my_table SET col_2 = 0 WHERE col_1 NOT IN (12,13,14,15);`

Is it possible to put these 2 codes in just one line of code? What needs to change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET col_2 = CASE WHEN col_1 IN (12, 13, 14, 15) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```